# How to read gzipped hdf5 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I usually read my hdf5 files with:

```
pd.read_hdf('path/to/file.h5', 'some_key')
```

To save some disk space, I plan to compress some old files using gzip.

How do I read a `.h5.gz` file into pandas HDFStore?

I can decompress the file with python's built-in gzip, but pandas API for HDF5 only accepts path to file on the filesystem (which is a string), not in-memory file object.

Comment: HDF5 includes built-in gzip compression. When creating the data, you have to option to enable compression per dataset (for Python & h5py, in case you use that, see the [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#lossless-compression-filters). Else, you can use the command-line utility [h5repack](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Repack) from the HDF group. Then the data can be read transparently from any HDF5 reader.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Sadly, I am dealing with large amount of existing data, which was not written with compression originally. And for some other reason, I can't replace them with compressed ones. So I am looking for a solution that can decompress the file in memory and convert to dataframe.